# Broadcast intent receive error

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, google-cloud-messaging

I have created an app that uses GCM push notification service to send updates and notifications.
Here's the link of the app [Culrav](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mnnit.vinayakAj.culrav2k14)
The problem is on some of the devices, the app crashes on first run, especially on Kit-Kat. On feedback report, the error I've got is this:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent
act=mnnit.vinayakAj.culrav2k14.app.DISPLAY_MESSAGE flg=0x10 (has extras) } in 
mnnit.vinayakAj.culrav2k14.q@41c61758
at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:765)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4744)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Null parameters are not accepted
at a.a.a.a.a.d.<init>(Unknown Source)
at a.a.a.a.a.d.a(Unknown Source)
at mnnit.vinayakAj.culrav2k14.q.onReceive(Unknown Source)
at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:755)
```

The code for BroadcastReceiver is

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mHandleMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String newMessage = intent.getExtras().getString("MESSAGE");
        Crouton.makeText(getParent(), newMessage, Style.INFO).show();
    }
};
```

I am following the code provided by [AirBop](https://github.com/indigorose/airbop-client) GCM-Server service.
Please help me resolving this issue.

Comment: put  BroadcastReceiver code

Answer (score 0):

```
Bcoz of your SDK tools are maybe Upgrade version doesnt support.. for example you create your project in SDK min level is 8 but your android SDk version tools is APK level 19 means it may occurs so go to your SDk Folder and delete tools Folder and then Copy your cuurent version of SDk tools must be put it in your SDK Folder.
you are using low level APK version means it will generate this line bcoz you want to access high high level code in Upgrade version supported methods means this lines will shows of your methods..

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

and also set this line in your activity

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
            int shortAnimTime = getResources().getInteger(
                    android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);
or 
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }

Ref Below link: for Broadcast Receiver.

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html
-----------------------------------------------------------

'startService(i1);'//Start Service.
Use startActivityForResult() instead of startActivity() bcoz in service we use 'startActivityResult()'
method bcoz broadcast receiver will give the response of onresultActivity.. so you could use this line

Use 'startActivityForResult(intent,requestcode)' instead of 'startActivity()'.

thank you.
```

Comment: I am really sorry, but I could not understand what were you trying to say. 
I'm using SDK version 19 to create this app, and the problem is coming on 4.0+ devices.